# How to recover Ubuntu partition after computer failure?

Tags: data-recovery

Recently my computer broke down and the Linux Ubuntu 10.04 partition could not be loaded back. What should be done to recover it back? What could be the possible error?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you see when you turn ont he computer and exactly what it does. Could you also explain any steps you've taken to bring your computer back, such as reinstall windows etc.

Answer (score 2):

Testdisk may be helpful for you.

A video can be reached on: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg&feature=player_embedded

NOTE: Testdisk will bring back any partitions you accidentally erased or lost. But some data may not come back with the partition. However, you can gain access to that data when the partition table is available again.

Good luck!

BTW: Testdisk and useful information related can be reached clicking here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a "rescue" disk or just a live CD and run fsck on all of your partitions.

To do fsck:

Type **fsck partitionname** in terminal