# Recover ext2 filesystem after reformat?

Tags: data-recovery, format

I had an ext2 partition and by mistake I reformatted it to ext4.
I immediately noticed the problem because at the next reboot my system wouldn't mount the reformatted partition, which got a new UUID and therefore did not match the one in  `/etc/fstab`.

After reformatting I did not write anything to the disk.
Is there any chance I can recover the data files on this partition?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  I have never tried the following steps, but there are several links to data recovery in AskUbuntu:

[Partitions disappeared after power loss while installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#46309)

http://www.geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/

[How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: The problem is that I did a reformat, I am afraid all the filesystem information is lost and there is no way to reconstruct where all the files are, even though the data may still be there. I am not 100 % sure though.

Comment: @Giorgio  I understand - the tools in the links may be able to recover some data, although I would read through the posts carefully prior to using any of them.

Comment: @Giorgio take it as a learning task, any positive outcome is a bonus. In the process you will find ways to do things to get it back NEXT TIME you make a mistake, OR learn what to AVOID. Been there doing similar stuff myself. Good luck!

Comment: @Hannu: I am the paranoid kind of person, especially when working on partitions, but sometimes your mind just goes on its own: after checking twice that `/dev/sdb1` was empty, I umounted it, thought `sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` and typed `sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1`.

Comment: If the `ext4` format overwrites all the `ext2` filesystem information, then I have no chance. I could recover some isolate files but I won't be able to reconstruct the disk's content. So, is there a chance that ext4 and ext2 write filesystem information on different blocks?

Comment: I can recover individual files with `foremost` but this is pretty useless if I cannot recover the directory structure.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery, http://askubuntu.com/questions/240372/how-to-recover-data-from-ext4-partitions, http://askubuntu.com/questions/41601/is-there-any-recovery-software-available-for-ext4 - seems to be worth reading.

Comment: I ended up recovering files with foremost and comparing them to my latest backup using a Python script I have written myself. It seems I did not loose any data: all recovered files were also in the backup.