# Cannot find hard drives after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive

Okay, I am not a much experienced Linux user.Recently my Windows 7 went bad and I installed Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu 13.10 (a triple boot). This morning I thought that I should only keep one OS and put in the Ubuntu Saucy CD. I selected the "Erase everything and install" option in the install menu. I thought that would only erase the other OSs but when I booted into the recently installed Ubuntu, I found out that I could not find any mounted hard drive on nautilus. I am confused and do not know what to do. This is the output of `sudo lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 296.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1 102.3M  0 rom
```

Comment: since you've _"erased everything and installed"_ Ubuntu, you might like these links: [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery), [Data recovery software available for ext4 filesystem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41601/is-there-any-recovery-software-available-for-ext4) if you have some important data to recover; if you do, make sure you do it before they get overwritten..

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.. what mounted drives do expect to see?

Comment: @psusi I expected to see the 84GB, 84GB, 68 and 57GB file systems on nautilus. BTW I got an answer to this question and now I understand! I was a newbie about partitioning then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose "Erase everything and install Ubuntu" option, your whole disk will be erased, which means your disk will be formatted. If there are multiple disks in your computer the "Erase everything and install Ubuntu" option will only erase the selected disk, but it won't erase the other disk(s). Then the installer installs Ubuntu on a created ext4 partition and then it also creates a separate SWAP partition on the extended partition according to the swap size given. On new installations of Ubuntu 17.04 and later a swap file will be created instead of a separate swap partition.

Comment: But I cannot see the mounted drives on the left of Nautilus...What do I do about that?

Comment: yes your whole disk was formatted.You can see only the root partition.

Comment: Post the output of `lsblk` command on your question.

Comment: Before the recent Ubuntu installation, I could see four mounted drives (84GB, 84GB, 68GB, 57GB), but now I cannot see them.That's what I meant.

Comment: your whole disk was formattted, all the partitions on that disk are deleted.For more clearance post only the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 296.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1 102.3M  0 rom

Comment: post the output in your question please.

Comment: yes like i said you had one ext4 partition with 296 GB and a swap partition.All the  partitions which are in the disk before are deleted.

Comment: Okay,then... BTW thanks a lot for the quick response :)