# Recover overwritten annotated pdf

Tags: 18.04, data-recovery, pdf, okular

I had annotated a pdf in Okular that had been generated via pdflatex and saved it. I was able to open and see the annotations.

However, I guess I did a `Ctrl-S` on the tex file by mistake and that over-wrote the whole pdf and I've lost all my annotations.

Is there any way in which I can recover the annotations of my pdf?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Okular 1.7.2

Comment: see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/543159/can-i-recover-a-deleted-file/543168#543168  there's even less chance of there being anything to recover when you overwrite compared to `rm` (because old information is actually written over).  Recommended for the future to use version control software or to at least use a different file name for your working document.  This would be sound advice for any OS.

Comment: I guess you may recover the annotations only if you have a backup or use some versioning system. I use Dropbox for my documents and it has a handy feature to restore previous versions of the file. Has saved me a few times.