# Any way to recover data on a re-installed Ubuntu OS on same partition?

Tags: 11.10, installation, 11.04, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatted and lost 6 years worth of photo memories.. any way to get this back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back)
>   [Best tools to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files/25364#25364)
>   [How do I recover Ubuntu partition after computer failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13030/how-to-recover-ubuntu-partition-after-computer-failure/25366#25366)

One day before I had **Ubuntu 11.10** on my laptop I was trying to install an mp3 application during the process something broke *(As far as I know it removed **bin** and **usr** directory for some weird reason)* and from the next reboot it was not going further **grub screen**, one black screen with no information on it.

I had then re-installed *(**Without formatting the partition**)* **Ubuntu 11.04** on the same and the only partition I have. Do you or anyone in your knowledge know, how to get the old data back?? Any help or reference to help me out of this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i am very sorry my friend the chances of getting back the data are very less i would like to say *ZERO*

Comment: If you didn't format then there is nothing gone to get back.  If you did format, then it's time to restore from backup.

Comment: I didn't format it. I just installed `11.04` on top of `11.10` which was not booting at all.

Answer (score 1):

Any way take a look at this:

[Best tool to recover removed files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files/25364#25364)

[Formatted and lost 6 years worth of photo memories.. any way to get this back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back/32711#32711)

[How to recover Ubuntu partition after computer failure?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13030/how-to-recover-ubuntu-partition-after-computer-failure/25366#25366)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Where the answers of some other people under those questions may also be helpful for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll keep this post updated if, anything works out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't format the partition , only `*conflicted*` files , e.g /bin/ls is removed by the installer , which means you need no data recovery files,  they are just there.

Otherwise it's replaced by the installer , there's no way to get it back.

Suggestion:

next time try to move your old files into a different folder before installation , e.g

```
mkdir /old
mv /.* /old
```

Note:  You may not get enough disk space to install if you did this.

**EDIT**

---

@Surya i won't expect a data recovery since you didn't format your hdd , make it short here , inode wasn't changing which means the data pointing to will be replaced , so impossible to find even a clue for those files being replaced. (But don't format it after seeing this ..)

And for the partition creating issue:

It's simple , but you need another bootable media to launch the following process:

Start another system , with e.g you ubuntu live cd or a USB start disk (there's a USB disk creator tool , search in software-center)

Try with `resize2fs` to resize your partition , and use `fdisk` to create another one when done

Comment: Does it include `home/user_name/Desktop/` data too??

Comment: @Surya , that won't be overwritten by the installer , just switch to that folder and take a look. I've done this in the old days , creating a user in the same name won't kill existing file in /home

Comment: I did check `home/user_name/Desktop/` using **testdisk** but it doesn't show me any deleted files. May be they are untracked?? And yes I have created the same user_name I had before re-install. I've also tried **foremost** it doesn't show much information too. I feel I'm lost now :'( Well now for future I want to create a new partition and since I have only one drive(unfortunately which is a primary drive :( ). Is there any way to create a partition on that?? Or do I have to format and install the OS again after creating new partitions?? Please help!!

Comment: @Surya , see the update , it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use forensic tools like "photorec,testdisk,foremost,seluthkit,extcarve" to salvage some data out of the disk.