# Problem while recovering 1TB disk erased with startup disk creator using testdisk

Tags: data-recovery

I was trying to make a bootable flash drive from the startup disk creator, and when I went to erase the flash drive I accidentally erased the wrong drive, a 1TB removable drive.

The operation took less than a second and gave no warning. I tried erasing the flash drive and it took about a minute, but it took but a second to erase the 1 TB drive, which is very surprising.

I followed the following steps mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120799/recover-1tb-disk-erased-with-startup-disk-creator), but they did not work. After pressing <kbd>P</kbd>, `testdisk` just shows some files with garbage names.

Please help me to recover my data.

Comment: plz edit your question.

Comment: You can try out R-studio: http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/Download.shtml one of the best recvery tool, and pretty easy to use

Answer (score 0):

> 11. [P] for list files and look if it seems it
>   12. [q] to quit list files
>   13. [Enter]
>   14. Write to save new partition table to MBR.

<kbd>P</kbd> only shows you the files, **not recover them**. You have to press <kbd>q</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then write the partition table. That's all!