# Unable to find Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I was also using windows 8. I was preparing an un-allocated partition of 25 GB from Windows to Ubuntu.

In the installation of Ubuntu I did not find the option of "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8", so I've chosen "something else" & selected sda then clicked new partition table, created a swap area around 4GB. Finally the rest partitioned as root for the system with size of 20GB.

Once  the installation finished; neither can I boot into Windows nor find my NTFS partitions (C, D, E).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda so it would be possible to say whether you deleted your Windows partitions or whether they still exist (somewhere)? Thanks

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the result
http://i.imgur.com/1QHvnAa.png 
and a screenshot for gparted
http://i.imgur.com/6cq9qKG.png
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't find any of my partitions after reinstalling Ubuntu. What to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464765/i-dont-find-any-of-my-partitions-after-reinstalling-ubuntu-what-to-do) -- or -- [Lost all my partition after installing Ubuntu 14.4 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469080/lost-all-my-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-14-4-lts/469132)  -- or -- [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206)

Comment: I'm sorry to say you've trashed your Windows installation. You may be able to recover individual files with [PhotoRec,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) but that's about it. You'll have to re-install the OS itself. If you've got a backup, use it. If not, now you know why people keep telling you to keep backups. Sorry, but that's the harsh reality.

Answer (score 0):

You should have zapped the GPT data before if you could not find the windows partitions. Now, of you are able to boot into Ubuntu, installed gparted and check if the windows partition has boot marked on it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the result of the command sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
http://i.imgur.com/1QHvnAa.png 
and a screenshot for gparted
http://i.imgur.com/6cq9qKG.png
thanks

Comment: Now this seems serious. Your windows partitions are being marked as unallocated.

Comment: what now ?? plz help

Comment: I am really sorry to say but I think you wiped your disk now.

Comment: You can try installing test disk from Ubuntu software centre and see if it recovers your partitions

Comment: Do I need an external hard drive to recover data to, or can I recover data on the save hard drive of my laptop ?

Comment: I am not very experienced with this but I don't think you need an external hard drive. But i suggest you to wait till some one experienced answers this thread.

Comment: Your most welcome :)

Comment: When you partition your drive from Ubuntu installer and Ubuntu is not detecting your windows partition, then you format the partition.

Answer (score 0):

> We are very sorry to inform you that your Windows partition has died after a violent purge from the Ubuntu installer.

[image]

As you can see in the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, only two partitons are detected :

- A Linux partition with a boot flag, probably your `/` filesystem.
- An extended partition, which actually is a swap.

According to gparted, the rest is *unallocated disk space*, meaning it has no filesystem, no partitionning scheme, nothing. This is quite like a no man's land.

It is very likely that pieces of your (naturally) fragmented Windows data is spread all over the disk, including in the unallocated space. However, without a proper partitionning scheme and a filesystem, this data is meaning-less and inaccessible. Re-formating the space might cause another loss of data.

Sadly, the comment from Rod Smith is true : everything got messed up. You might be able to recover a few things, but that's it. If you want a piece of advice... this is a good occasion to start over in a beautiful, Linux-based, universe (I'm trying to see the positive, only the positive!)

Comment: I will never use Ubuntu after all these problem it caused to me.
Thanks for reply [THUMBS UP]

Comment: I am afraid the problem never came from Ubuntu, this is nothing but a user blunder :) It did exactly what you asked, you just asked for the wrong thing.