# How to add a GRUB2 menu entry for booting multiple Linux OS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I already had RHEL 7 on my HDD(I have only one) and now recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I am unable to create Grub2 entry so that I can use both OS, currently I can only use Ubuntu.

**The result for #fdisk -l is :**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00098227

 Device    Boot   Start       End         Blocks    Id  System
/dev/sda1   *   314574848   524290046   104857599+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       524292094   976771071   226239489    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       524292096   874369023   175038464    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       875397120   976771071    50686976   8e  Linux LVM 

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 4043 MB, 4043309056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 491 cylinders, total 7897088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap doesn't contain a valid partition table

```
Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 47.9 GB, 47857008640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5818 cylinders, total 93470720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: Did your run  `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: That's it. It will check what OSes are installed.

Comment: Ya I did that. The result is ...........

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sdb1
Found Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo) on /dev/mapper/rhel-root
done

Comment: Make sure fast boot ans secure boot is disabled in bios- update your grub 'sudo update-grub"

Comment: @DnrDevil I check my bios, there were not such options like **fast boot**_and_ **secure boot** . I did **sudo update-grub2** and the result says **Found Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo) on /dev/mapper/rhel-root**.

Comment: It says it found the Red Hat install? So does that not boot? Normally you have to install the lvm2 driver and also mount the lvm partitions for grub to find installs inside a LVM.

Answer (score 2):

Normally Red Hat and related distributions use an LVM configuration in which there's an LVM partition (which you've got) with at least a couple of logical volumes (which you've got) and a separate `/boot` partition (which you don't seem to have). Without the `/boot` partition, you won't be able to boot RHEL, since your system won't have a kernel, which is absolutely essential for booting. My suspicion is that you accidentally deleted your RHEL `/boot` partition when you installed Ubuntu, which I suspect exists on your `/dev/sda1`. I can't be 100% positive of this diagnosis, though.

There is one small glimmer of hope: Your `/dev/sda1` starts at sector 314,574,848, which means there's about 150 GiB of unallocated space at the start of the disk. If `/boot` was originally in that space, then it may be possible to recover it with [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) You may want to look into that possibility:

A caveat: If I'm right, changing your disk's partition layout runs the risk of creating new problems or making your current problem worse. Doing a low-level backup of the entire disk is a wise precaution. You'd do that with something like:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/lots/of/space/sda-backup/img
```

This command is likely to take several hours to complete. You'll need another disk that's at least a little bit larger than your current `/dev/sda`, mounted somewhere so that `/path/to/lots/of/space` will reside on that larger disk.

Comment: Thank you @RodSmith for the information. I tried **TestDisk** and was lost, thanks god only the grub entry was erased. I just reinstall grub in /dev/sda and able to use Ubuntu. Will you please mail me or give more info to recover /boot. I am in real need.

Comment: There's lots of TestDisk documentation on the Web. You might start with [this official TestDisk tutorial](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) or [this AskUbuntu question and answer.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469080/lost-all-my-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-14-4-lts)