# Lost main directory after fsck file system repairs

Tags: mount

I did file system repairs on my 475 GB partition on an external USB hard drive. with main(root) directory named xyz. After the repairs by `fsck`, when I connect it to the computer the partition is not mounted.

*How can I get my data back?*

The output of "lsblk" with HD attached is :

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN  RM     SIZE  RO   TYPE    MOUNTPOINT  
sda         8:0     0   149.1G  0    disk
sda1        8:1     0    10  G  0    part
sda2        8:2     0   139  G  0    part
sdc         8:32    1     1.9G  0    disk
sdc1        8:33    1     1.9G  0    part   /cdrom
sdd         8:48    0   465.8G  0    disk
sdd1        8:49    0    18.7G  0    part
sdd2        8:50    0     4.7G  0    part
sdd3        8:51    0   442.4G  0    part /media/ubuntu/356d60dc-80a5-40b4-8a20-117322d45
sr0         11:0    1  1024M    0    rom
loop0        7:0    0   952M    1   loop  /rofs
```

The output of `lsblk` without HD is without the details of sdd.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the output of `lsblk` with and without the HDD attached. Then leave a comment @fabby

Comment: @fabby  I have edited the details with output of the lsblk command with and without HD attached.I hope you can help me to get my data back.

Comment: @fabby : I followed the commands. At the "mount" command the reply was: " mount : only root can do that". I tried with sudo mount and the reply was " mount : special device sdd3 does not exist"

Answer (score 2):

To mount your HDD again type:

```
sudo mkdir /media/data
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/data
sudo mount /dev/sdd3 /media/data
```

And you should have everything back in `/media/data`

Comment: @heemayl: sorry! I was still editing!

Comment: No worries..+1 will be here forever :)

Comment: @fabby  I followed the commands. At the "mount" command the reply was: " mount : only root can do that". I tried with sudo mount and the reply was " mount : special device sdd3 does not exist"

Comment: I might add that I am on live usb. My ubuntu 14.04 installation is not working which was on 20 GB partition.,and I am trying to rescue my data which is on 475 GB partition. As for reinstallation of 14.04 ,I have done it two times but each time it developed problems- may be because of bad sectors on the hard disk. Actually the disk is quite new. Any ideas as to what should I do to avoid bad sectors during reinstallation of 14.04?

Comment: @user124456: Fabby's `mount` command was erroneous (wrong device path). Please try again with my edit! If the mount command results in an error message, please include it in your question.

Comment: @David Foerster : The reply to the command" mount /dev/sdd3 /media/data  was as earlier " mount: only root can do that"

Comment: Try sudo again! (sorry, edited once more)

Comment: @fabby: The reply to sudo command is" mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd3 ...etc. The dmesg |tail output is: exr4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group --- not in group...! ext4 group descriptors corrupted. I am afraid to start again the fsck repiars, as they have not helped at all. Btw did you see my comment about being on live usb and how to avoid bad sectors while reinstallation of 14.04 on /dev/sdd ?

Comment: yes, I saw that, but that's a totally [different question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) already [asked here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120799/recover-1tb-disk-erased-with-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: @fabby: So, is there any way for me to recover my data other than completely copying on other bigger disk by "dd" and then try these methods again?

Comment: This is not a forum: if the answer above answered your original question, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)** If you have any additional questions, [just ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  It's not like they cost you any additional money...  **>:-) ;-)**