# How do I fix Master File Table using Ubuntu?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

So my friend accidentally messed up his MFT and MFTMirr of his NTFS windows 7 drive while installing Ubuntu (my guess is that he messed up the re-partitioning of his drive or something of the sort. He says that he has no idea how he did it)

He can boot Ubuntu but booting Windows just fails.

Does anyone know a good linux program to fix the MFT??

If it cannot be done does anyone know a good way to recover some of his files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) on this site you'll find useful previous answers which cover both your needs for restoring a deleted partition table and bring back a whole partition after it's messed up or deleted, the same for your needs about file recovering. This list contains just a few but you may find more by following this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery

1. [How to recover Deleted Files and Folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders)
2. [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)
3. [Recovering data from /](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194090/recovering-data-from)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. It eventually turned out that he didn't destroy his MFT but that windows is just being windows. I got him to share his desktop over the internet with me and I tried mounting his drives using the terminal and that worked including all his data.

Comment: That's excellent news! :D Glad to know you saved the data. Now I suggest you to backup and re-format any comprised partitions in order to make sure the data is safe again and stored properly using the right amount of clusters. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To repair the Windows MTF the only known tool that will do it without problems is the `chkdsk /f` since it checks the MTF/mirr and repair any inconsistency. Sadly, NTFS as proprietary filesystem, there isn't any reliable tool to do this outside Windows, you can however, see the files if the MTF isn't too damaged using ntfs-3g driver.

Comment: sadly `chkdsk /f` just removed all the entries from my MFT. Maybe [`Testdisk`](https://askubuntu.com/a/171179) could have helped me, but after `chkdsk` it was late.